# Abrir página com form ativo

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para abrir uma página nova com um campo do formulário ativo, pois pelo padrão quando abre uma página nenhum campo está ativo, ou seja é preciso ir com o mouse e clicar em cima de algum campo, não sendo possível navegar diretamente com o TAB.

Exemplo:

```
            <div class="row">


                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label class="col-md-12" >CAMPO1</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input name="campo1" type="text" class="form-control" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label class="col-md-12" >CAMPO2</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input name="campo2" type="text" class="form-control" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>                          

            </div>
```

Como eu faria para no caso acima o teclado já estar setado no campo1 direto para preenchimento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione `autofocus` na tag do input que deseja fazer isso, exemplo

`<input name="campo1" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus>`

Comment: Perfeito, valeu!